# C program for ROT13 encoding

Tags: c

I've tried to make a code that encrypts a message in ROT13, i'll leave here the whole code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 500
int main(){
  int i,diff[i];
    char string[MAX];
    printf("\x1b[34mHello friend,this is a simple ROT13 decryption algorhytm brought to you by @NikoScaccia\x1b[0m\n");
    printf("\x1b[31mPlease Enjoy!!!\x1b[0m\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Insert a phrase: \n");
    printf("\x1b[0,35mMAX LEN: %d\x1b[0m\n",MAX);
    scanf("%99[^\n]",string);
      for(i=0;i<'\0';i++){
                if(string[i]<='a' && string[i]<='z' || string[i]>='A' && string[i]<='Z'||!isspace(string[i])){

        string[i]=tolower(string[i]);
      }
        else {
          printf("Invalid Input!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      }
      for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){
        if(string[i]!=' '){
          if((int)string[i]+13<=122){
                string[i]=(int)string[i]+13;
          }
          else {
            if(string[i]!='n'){
            diff[i]=122-(int)string[i];
            string[i]=(int)string[i]+diff[i];
            string[i]= (int)string[i]-26+13-diff[i];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      printf("Encrypting...\n");
      printf("Encrypted message: %s\n",string);
      return 0;
}
```

the code compiles correctly but it has two main problems,it seems to translate correctly every letter in the alphabet except for the letter 'n' which for some reason translates to '{',
also if I try to feed the program something like "hello man" it executes correctly(except obviously for the letter n),while if for example I try "hello friend" i get a segmentation fault error.
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First line in `main()`: `int i,diff[i];` What is the value of `i` here? What will the size of the array be?

Comment: Also at `for(i=0;i<'\0';i++){` I think you want `for(i = 0; string[i]; i++) {`

Comment: Side note: you tell the user to enter a string up to `MAX` size, but then limit it to `99` in the `scanf`.

Comment: ROT13 is an encoding, not an encryption.

Comment: How many iterations are you thinking this will allow:`for(i=0;i<'\0';i++){`  ?

Comment: Funnily enough `'{'` is just beyond `'z'`. Off-by-one somewhere?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's because when I initially used fgets,than when I was troubleshooting I tried changing it this way,with no effect obviously

Comment: @ryyker yeah I know,I originally used fgets,then changed to scanf to see if it had any effect on the execution

Comment: Note: SO is not a forum. It's a Q&A platform only. Discussions are at a minimum and only allowed (minimally) in the comments.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes I noticed that too,but I can't really spot the flaw in the algorithm,also if it was 1 letter off wouldn't it be the same for the other letters right?

Comment: IMHO, `scanf()` has its place in the world, but `fgets()` with a little parsing has been easier to use for me when dealing with user input.

Comment: my bad @Rob,as I said I'm new and I apologized in advance for anything wrong I said or did

Comment: @ryyker totaly agree with you,but switching back to fgets,and also changing '\0' with strlen(string) in the for loop doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: @ryyker Perhaps "could be written as `scanf("%499[^\n]",string)` and still be safe"  (499 vs 498.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Yes, Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use hard-coded character codes like `122`. that is `'z'` so it is clearer and less error-prone to use it.

Comment: @johnnyMopp I just realized what you meant with your first comment and now I feel really stupid

Comment: Solved it,just had to change that i in the  diff variable ,can't believe I didn't see it,thank you @JohnnyMopp

Comment: _"Solved it,just had to change that i in the diff variable"_.  Ummm, that was not the only issue.  Take a moment to peruse the answer(s) :)

Comment: I see `if(...&& ... || ... && ...||...)` and just immediately assumed that was the bug. Use parenthesis and named values PLEASE

Comment: yes I know @rykker I also changed the for loop putting strlen(string) instead of '\0' and fixed the wrong compare in the first if and it works just fine

Comment: what do you mean @Mooing Duck?

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**Uninitialized `i`**

`i` is not known when `diff[i]` is defined.  Array size unknown, potentially invalid.

```
int i,diff[i];  // Bad
```

Do not define `diff[]` until after `i` is assigned.
Define `diff[]` after the  `for(i=0; string[i]; i++){...}` loop below.

**Wrong compare**

Loop never iterates.

```
// for(i=0;i<'\0';i++){
for(i=0; string[i]; i++){
```

**Wrong compare**

`<=` vs. `>=`

```
//string[i]<='a' && string[i]<='z'
string[i]>='a' && string[i]<='z'
```

**Unneeded compare**

Why test `string[i]` is not a space?

```
// if(...  || !isspace(string[i])) {
if(...){
```

---

**Simplification**

Tests not needed.

```
  //      for(i=0;i<'\0';i++){
  //          if(string[i]<='a' && string[i]<='z' || string[i]>='A' && string[i]<='Z'||!isspace(string[i])){
  //  string[i]=tolower(string[i]);
  //}

  for(i=0; string[i]; i++){
    string[i]=tolower((unsigned char) string[i]);
  }
  int diff[i];  // Now define `diff[]`
```

Comment: That is true but should not affect the lowercase operation it controls. There isn't any need to test the character anyway: `tolower()` only lowercases uppercase characters.

Comment: I would be more concerned with the loop control `for(i=0;i<'\0';i++)`

Comment: the problem was the i in the initialization of the diff variable,thank you guys